# How to target individually nested elements using CSS

Tags: html, css, nested, css-selectors

I'm trying to target each span individually in a structure like below. I've tried `nth-child()` & `nth-of-type()` but it didn't work, it was only applying the first style to all of the spans. Anyone no know how to do this without giving each a separate IDs?

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you didn't put the spans in divs, nth-child would work.. Putting single spans in divs is rather redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
div > div:nth-of-type(n) > span {

}
```

where `(n)` will be number of the `div`

Comment: @Travis he want to target span individually by its parent div how can it be done without it

Comment: @Travis yes my first expression was that too, that you have misread the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
div>div>span{

}
```